Docker compose problem while running Java spring and postgresql application
Dockerfile:
FROM openjdk:23
ADD /BankAccountMicroservice/build/libs/start-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar app.jar
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "app.jar"]

Compose.yaml:
version: '3.8'
services:

  database:
    image: 'postgres:latest'
    container_name: bankAccountDB
    #restart: always
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
    environment:
      - 'POSTGRES_DB=bankAccount'
      - 'POSTGRES_PASSWORD=msone'
      - 'POSTGRES_PASSWORD_ROOT=msone'
      - 'POSTGRES_USER=postgres'
      - 'POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust'
    extra_hosts:
      - 'host.docker.internal:host-gateway'
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD", "mysqladmin" ,"ping", "-h", "localhost" ]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5
      
  app:
    image: 'app:latest'
    container_name: bankAccountApp
    #restart: always
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      database:
        condition: service_healthy
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    environment:
      - 'POSTGRES_DATASOURCE_USERNAME: postgres'
      - 'POSTGRES_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD: msone'

Hello it's kinda my first time using Docker & Docker compose environnement I'm not used to it if someone could help me that would be great, my API REST is running perfectly fine while i'm doing it on my device (locally) but when i'm trying to run image it after building it with Docker (vscode extension), with that command "docker run -it <nameofimage> i'm getting errors like I can't access to my database or something I think.
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/

 :: Spring Boot ::       (v3.3.0-SNAPSHOT)

2024-05-13T13:27:30.293Z  INFO 1 --- [start] [           main] com.run.start.Application                : Starting Application v0.0.1-SNAPSHOT using Java 23-ea with PID 1 (/app.jar started by root in /)
2024-05-13T13:27:30.298Z  INFO 1 --- [start] [           main] com.run.start.Application                : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2024-05-13T13:27:31.921Z  INFO 1 --- [start] [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JDBC repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2024-05-13T13:27:32.011Z  INFO 1 --- [start] [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 80 ms. Found 1 JDBC repository interface.
2024-05-13T13:27:32.722Z  INFO 1 --- [start] [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port 8080 (http)
2024-05-13T13:27:32.740Z  INFO 1 --- [start] [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2024-05-13T13:27:32.741Z  INFO 1 --- [start] [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.20]
2024-05-13T13:27:32.789Z  INFO 1 --- [start] [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2024-05-13T13:27:32.791Z  INFO 1 --- [start] [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2323 ms
2024-05-13T13:27:32.985Z  INFO 1 --- [start] [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : bankAccount - Starting...
2024-05-13T13:27:34.059Z  WARN 1 --- [start] [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'jdbcClientRunRepository' defined in URL [jar:nested:/app.jar/!BOOT-INF/classes/!/com/run/start/runner/JdbcClientRunRepository.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/sql/init/DataSourceInitializationConfiguration.class]: Failed to execute database script
2024-05-13T13:27:34.065Z  INFO 1 --- [start] [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2024-05-13T13:27:34.075Z  INFO 1 --- [start] [           main] .s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLogger :

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2024-05-13T13:27:34.087Z ERROR 1 --- [start] [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'jdbcClientRunRepository' defined in URL [jar:nested:/app.jar/!BOOT-INF/classes/!/com/run/start/runner/JdbcClientRunRepository.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/sql/init/DataSourceInitializationConfiguration.class]: Failed to execute database script
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:795) ~[spring-beans-6.1.7-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:6.1.7-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:237) ~[spring-beans-6.1.7-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:6.1.7-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1357) ~[spring-beans-6.1.7-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:6.1.7-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1194) ~[spring-beans-6.1.7-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:6.1.7-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:562) ~[spring-beans-6.1.7-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:6.1.7-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522) ~[spring-beans-6.1.7-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:6.1.7-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:337) ~[spring-beans-6.1.7-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:6.1.7-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.1.7-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:6.1.7-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-6.1.7-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:6.1.7-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.1.7-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:6.1.7-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:975) ~[spring-beans-6.1.7-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:6.1.7-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:962) ~[spring-context-6.1.7-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:6.1.7-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:624) ~[spring-context-6.1.7-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:6.1.7-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.3.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:3.3.0-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-3.3.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:3.3.0-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:456) ~[spring-boot-3.3.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:3.3.0-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:335) ~[spring-boot-3.3.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:3.3.0-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1363) ~[spring-boot-3.3.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:3.3.0-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1352) ~[spring-boot-3.3.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:3.3.0-SNAPSHOT]
        at com.run.start.Application.main(Application.java:16) ~[!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.launch.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:91) ~[app.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.launch.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:53) ~[app.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.launch.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:58) ~[app.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/sql/init/DataSourceInitializationConfiguration.class]: Failed to execute database script
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1788) ~[spring-beans-6.1.7-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:6.1.7-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:600) ~[spring-beans-6.1.7-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:6.1.7-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522) ~[spring-beans-6.1.7-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:6.1.7-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:337) ~[spring-beans-6.1.7-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:6.1.7-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.1.7-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:6.1.7-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-6.1.7-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:6.1.7-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.1.7-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:6.1.7-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:313) ~[spring-beans-6.1.7-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:6.1.7-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.1.7-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:6.1.7-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254) ~[spring-beans-6.1.7-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:6.1.7-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1443) ~[spring-beans-6.1.7-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:6.1.7-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1353) ~[spring-beans-6.1.7-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:6.1.7-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:904) ~[spring-beans-6.1.7-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:6.1.7-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:782) ~[spring-beans-6.1.7-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:6.1.7-SNAPSHOT]
        ... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.UncategorizedScriptException: Failed to execute database script
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.DatabasePopulatorUtils.execute(DatabasePopulatorUtils.java:67) ~[spring-jdbc-6.1.7-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:6.1.7-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.jdbc.init.DataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer.runScripts(DataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer.java:87) ~[spring-boot-3.3.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:3.3.0-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.sql.init.AbstractScriptDatabaseInitializer.runScripts(AbstractScriptDatabaseInitializer.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.3.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:3.3.0-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.sql.init.AbstractScriptDatabaseInitializer.applyScripts(AbstractScriptDatabaseInitializer.java:108) ~[spring-boot-3.3.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:3.3.0-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.sql.init.AbstractScriptDatabaseInitializer.applySchemaScripts(AbstractScriptDatabaseInitializer.java:98) ~[spring-boot-3.3.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:3.3.0-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.sql.init.AbstractScriptDatabaseInitializer.initializeDatabase(AbstractScriptDatabaseInitializer.java:76) ~[spring-boot-3.3.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:3.3.0-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.sql.init.AbstractScriptDatabaseInitializer.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractScriptDatabaseInitializer.java:66) ~[spring-boot-3.3.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:3.3.0-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1835) ~[spring-beans-6.1.7-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:6.1.7-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1784) ~[spring-beans-6.1.7-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:6.1.7-SNAPSHOT]
        ... 37 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Failed to obtain JDBC Connection
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:84) ~[spring-jdbc-6.1.7-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:6.1.7-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.DatabasePopulatorUtils.execute(DatabasePopulatorUtils.java:52) ~[spring-jdbc-6.1.7-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:6.1.7-SNAPSHOT]
        ... 45 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:346) ~[postgresql-42.7.3.jar!/:42.7.3]
        at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:54) ~[postgresql-42.7.3.jar!/:42.7.3]
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:273) ~[postgresql-42.7.3.jar!/:42.7.3]
        at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:446) ~[postgresql-42.7.3.jar!/:42.7.3]
        at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:298) ~[postgresql-42.7.3.jar!/:42.7.3]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:137) ~[HikariCP-5.1.0.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:360) ~[HikariCP-5.1.0.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:202) ~[HikariCP-5.1.0.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:461) ~[HikariCP-5.1.0.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:550) ~[HikariCP-5.1.0.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:98) ~[HikariCP-5.1.0.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:111) ~[HikariCP-5.1.0.jar!/:na]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.fetchConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:160) ~[spring-jdbc-6.1.7-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:6.1.7-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:118) ~[spring-jdbc-6.1.7-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:6.1.7-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:81) ~[spring-jdbc-6.1.7-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:6.1.7-SNAPSHOT]
        ... 46 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnect(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnectNow(Net.java:682) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.timedFinishConnect(NioSocketImpl.java:542) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:592) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:327) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:760) ~[na:na]
        at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.createSocket(PGStream.java:243) ~[postgresql-42.7.3.jar!/:42.7.3]
        at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.<init>(PGStream.java:98) ~[postgresql-42.7.3.jar!/:42.7.3]
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:136) ~[postgresql-42.7.3.jar!/:42.7.3]
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:262) ~[postgresql-42.7.3.jar!/:42.7.3]
        ... 60 common frames omitted

I tried following many guides and others stackoverflow posts but It's not working at all :(
I would like it to run it correctly on Docker? without all these errors.

You need to set the Spring spring.datasource.url property to point at the database container, possibly via a SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL environment variable in the Compose file.  Note that the syntax of the app: { environment: [] } is wrong as you've written it; it should look like the database: { environment: [] }.
